# to join someone in doing something or on doing something

Tags: prepositions

- Would you like to join us in watching the football game tonight?

I want to know which is correct, in or on? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I suggest you reconsider how to build your sentence using "would like".

Comment: you can't use _on_ because it's a phrasal verb - [join in](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/join-in-sth)

Comment: @jimsug, I don't think it's a phrasal verb. The _in_ is just a plain preposition. If we were using the phrasal verb _join in_, then we would have something like "Would you like to join in in watching the game?" (Yes, with a repeated _in_. It's looks pretty funny.) Another example: "Would you like to help us in eating the pretzels." It's the same structure, but there is no such phrasal verb as _help in_.

Comment: @Dangph Hmm. Interesting. Quite possibly, so I may be right for the wrong reasons.

Answer (score 1):

> Would you like to join us in watching the football game tonight?

Your sentence is correct and no change is need as [*jimsug*](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/1407/jimsug)
said in comments
you can't use **on** because it's a phrasal verb so **join in** is correct.

Comment: Ayodhya's answer is correct, but I'd add that the more common phrasing would probably be, "Would you like to watch the football came with us tonight?"

Comment: @Jay sounds good. replace came=game

Comment: Oops, typo, sorry. Yes, "game".

Answer (score 0):

Yep, people say that. You've retained the expression perfectly.